# Who has invited somebody, when and how to a Google Drive Spreadsheet?

Tags: security, google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

We have a sheet at my company with logins and passwords, shared with all the team, so all the people may enter in the supplier's intranets.

Today, in "shared with", where normally there are 6 to 8 people, I see a person that I don't know and does not belong to my team.

I need to know:

1. who of my team made the invitation,
2. when it was done, and
3. if it has been by manually writing the address in the "share with" box or it has been done by a sharing a link.

How can I "audit" this security issue? I'm the account admin. It's a free account.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm the account admin"? Are you using a Google common account or a G Suite legacy free edition?

Comment: G Suite legacy, ie: My own domain, but not paying until 10 users. But the file was shared with people from the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer in [Seguridad: ¿quién ha invitado a alguien, cuándo y cómo, a un spreadsheet?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=es#!topic/docs-es/Gs9KyJSG_0I;context-place=forum/docs-es) by Enoc Rosales

1. Locate the file on Google Drive
2. Select the file
3. Open the Details panel

   - Right click the file and select See details
   - Click on the i button on the Google Drive toolbar
4. Open the Activity tab

There will be listed who made what and when, including who shared a file.

Comment: Perfect! It effectively lists who added who and when, and who removed who and when. It's exactly what I was seeking for! Thnkx.